# Crystal how to convert Array(T) to Array(T?)

Tags: crystal-lang

I'm making `Serie` - an immutable time-series with missing values. But it can't be initialized without nulls.

```
class Serie(T)
  def initialize(@array = Array(T?).new); end

  def self.[](*values : T); Serie(T).new values.to_a.as(Array(T?)) end
  def self.[](*values : T?); Serie(T).new values.to_a end
end

Serie[1, nil, 2] # Works    
Serie[1, 2]      # Throws an Error
```

Also, it can't be initialized with array without explicit types and throws an error. Although it seems like there's enough information to infer the type.

```
Serie.new(Int32?)([1, nil, 2]) # Works
Serie.new([1, nil, 2])        # Throws an Error
```

P.S.

I'm using a hack to initialize it with `Serie.self[...]` do you know a way to initialize it as Array-like object `Serie{1, 2}` but avoid adding `<<` method because it's static immutable time series data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Array(T).new.as(Array(T?))` can't work because `Array(T?)` is not a valid restriction of `Array(T)` (Crystal's generics can't express covariance yet).

In order to transform from `Array(T)` to `Array(T?)` you need to actually create a new array of type `Array(T?)` and copy the items over. One way to do that is `values.map(&.as(T?))`.

<del>(Technically, you could also use unsafe type casts to get an instance of `Array(T?)` pointing at the same memory as the `Array(T)` because the binary representation is identical; but it easily breaks when adding `nil` values via the nilable instance.)</del>This is not actually true, the binary representation is different because of the union type.

> I'm using a hack to initialize it with Serie.self[...] do you know a way to initialize it as Array-like object Serie{1, 2} but avoid adding << method because it's static immutable time series data?

Adding a `self.[]` method is probably the best workaround for that. There is a discussion about changing the implementation of array-like literals to call a single method instead of transforming to a series of `<<` calls in [#5703](https://github.com/crystal-lang/crystal/issues/5703).

Comment: It almost works, thanks, one additional fix is to change the `self.[]` to union type `def self.[](*values : T | T?)` because the overload not distinguish between `def self.[](*values : T)` and `def self.[](*values : T?)` Not sure if it's a bug or by design